# How to solve this Parse error

Tags: opencart

After I logged in our website,

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in /home/hyuny276/public_html/ubpserver.com/view/template/common/home.tpl on line 291

line 291:
  %</td -->

Comment: go to the file /home/hyuny276/public_html/ubpserver.com/view/template/commo‌​n/home.tpl and copy line 291 into your question, we'll then be able to determine the error within the syntax

Comment: <!-- td class='center' colspan=2><b --><?-- php echo $row['percent']; --?><!-- /b> %</td --> <!-- JH 12/23/13 adeded last years's percent -->

Comment: Is that exactly how it's written because that should look something like: <td class='center' colspan=2><b><?php echo $row['percent'];?></b> %</td> <!-- JH 12/23/13 adeded last years's percent -->

Comment: It is solved!   Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 0):

There must be any syntax error in your home.tpl

1. Check if any PHP tag is not closed at line 291.
2. Check if any semicolon in PHP code is left at line 291.

You can check syntax error in Netbeans IDE for PHP. Just open the file in IDE.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Cool suggestions!   Just as you said.